# Sharing Files to Lightning Partner Community Members

Tags: lightning, partner-communities, libraries

I have a need to share a file with all the members of my community and ideally track downloads using a report.

My reading into the community [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htviewsolution?id=000214048&language=en_US) it looks like it should be possible but I am having trouble finding current information on how to make it work.

I have done the following steps on a Summer 16 sandbox and had no luck, any further assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I have a Community using the Napili template. 
In the enterprise salesforce, using the classic view I created a CRM Content Library, added the desired file and add the partner community members to the member list.

*Note: I know that libraries are not available in lightning experiences, but it is my understanding that the files from libraries are simply available in the files section and the library sharing rules still apply*

Inside the community I have put in a file listing component.

Expected Outcome: The file would appear in the shared files section of the component

Actual outcome: the file was not shared.